# mysql.sock is being created with the wrong permissions. What defines the permissions for the socket?

Tags: mysql, sockets

On a bare-bones new install (RHEL7) with mariadb-server installed, starting mariadb creates a socket file in /var/lib/mysql:

srwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql        0 May 25 08:23 mysql.sock

Our local installation procedure moves this directory and sets a symbolic link at /var/lib/mysql. This worked well for years, but in RHEL7 with current maintenance, starting mariadb now creates the mysql.sock file without write for group or others, making it impossible to connect to the database normally. On the effected systems, the socket now looks like:

srwxr-xr-x+ 1 mysql mysql          0 May 25 08:30 mysql.sock

How and where does the permissions for the socket get set? How can we change the setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the ACLs on the directory and file (though they should have granted access to the file, but evidently, sockets are handled differently).

Removing all the ACLs, and in this case, nobody should be in mariadb's data directory modifying anything anyway, so there was no impact in doing so, allowed the file to be created correctly with the proper permissions, and we were able to connect to the database. So, the solution is to not put ACLs on the directory or files.

Ah, what a tangled web we weave...

Answer (score 2):

The permissions get set when the socket file is created as you (re)start the mysql server. So I would guess that the default permissions are somewhere inside of the code that creates the socket.

Your socket file appears to be under ACL control (+), which I know little about, but have you tried `chmod a+w mysql.sock` ?

Comment: Indeed, I can change the protection on the socket with chmod a+w mysql.sock, and everything starts working as expected. However, if I restart mariadb or boot the system, the socket file goes back to its less-than-useful protection.

Your response did lead me to the ultimate solution though. So thank you.